# Lag when scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uicollectionview, lag

I have a `UITableView` which has around 10 cells. Each cell has a different `reusableIdentifier`. Each cell contains a `UICollectionView` with approx. 15 `UICollectionViewCells` in each row.

When `UITableViewCell` is created first time, on scroll there is a jerk. Once all the cells are created, scrolling seems to be smooth.
When I explicitly call `[collectionView reloadData]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView`, there is jerk.

This issue is observed in iPad only. There is no jerk when scrolling in iPhone. There is no processing / network calls on main thread.

Here is the code for cell for row at index path:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellId = indexPath.row % 5
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell\(cellId)") as! UITableViewCell        
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: It seams problem is with your collection view not with tableveiw. This is the reason of jerking in iPads only. iPad will have more collectionView cells then iPhone. Could you please show your code to make other understand your problem?

Comment: Can you paste in the code for cellForRow? You're probably overloading the main thread by loading 12 images (times number of visible rows) simultaneously

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought the same thing so returned collection view number of rows count as 1 but the jerk was still there. I have created custom table view and collection view cells in storyboard and added code for delegates in view controller. Cell for row at index path method for both table and collection view simply returns the cell with no other logic.